# PHP post data problems in Phonegap

Tags: php, android, cordova

I am using Phonegap 2.8.1 for an Android application and I am trying to get data from another php file via the following code.

```
$.post("http://m.webpage.com/App.php",postdata, function(result){
  $("#div_res").html(result);       
});
```

In android 2.3.3 version, i got the result clearly but in Android version 4.0(and the other latest versions), the result is empty. I can not find out any way to solve this problem. 
Thanx for your help.

Comment: first of all, make sure that your server is providing and receiving data.
secondly, make sure that the server is receiving the post data from the mobile (try `alert(postdata)`before the `$.post(..)`)
than please share with us the info that u'll get
if everything is okey try to change the function, use the normal $.ajax with Post method u can find it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It is about the white list. I have made some changes in whitelist. I have used "*" to allow all external urls in whitelist but it is not acceptable in Android vers. 4 and other new versions. Then, i added all the urls one by one to white list. Finally, application worked.